# Hyperlink from app to android browser doesn't load javascript

Tags: javascript, android, browser, refresh

I've created a basic html css app that contains a link to a mobile web page which contains a lighting calculator. The weird part is that when you go directly to the mobile webpage through the browser first the calculator (which uses javascript) works fine. On the other hand if you launch the app and click the link to go the calculator which launches the browser the calculator doesn't work unless you refresh the page. Does anyone have any idea or suggestion on what's happening here. Below is a link to the calculator page that I'm using.

[EverLast Calculator Web Page](http://www.everlastlight.com/lightingcalc/docs/about/costwait.html)

[EverLast Calculator App Download](http://www.everlastlight.com/downloads/app.apk)